# CSS3PIE not working in IE

Tags: css, drupal

I've got a PIE folder in my libraries directory, and css3pie module folder in my modules directory.

I've got the following css in my layout.css:

```
#block-block-1, #block-block-7, #triptych, #block-block-8 {     
    border: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
    padding: 10px 20px;    
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: #666 0px 2px 3px;
    -moz-box-shadow: #666 0px 2px 3px;
    box-shadow: #666 0px 2px 3px;
    background: #EEEEEE;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 bottom, from(#EEEEEE), to(#FFFFFF));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#EEEEEE, #FFFFFF);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#EEEEEE, #FFFFFF);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#EEEEEE, #FFFFFF);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#EEEEEE, #FFFFFF);
    background: linear-gradient(#EEEEEE, #FFFFFF);
    -pie-background: linear-gradient(#EEEEEE, #FFFFFF);
    behavior: url(/../libraries/pie/PIE.htc);
}
```

I've enabled the module and have the following option selected: Use theme settings
Use selector settings from theme info file.

The rounded corners are not working in IE, but they are working in Firefox. What am I missing?

[This site](http://docs.composite.net/) uses css3pie and it's meant to be working, but for me, on IE8 the corners are not rounded.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try removing the first forward slash in your behavior line and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `position: relative` into you CSS statement. I've had that issue a couple of times and it's normally resolved by doing that. Further information can be found at: http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/.